# Visual Studio Extending Ctrl + K, Ctrl + D

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am a bit lazy when it comes to formatting code in Visual Studio and almost rely solely on the magic of <kbd>Ctrl + K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl + D</kbd> (or <kbd>F</kbd> depending on what I’m doing). However I loathe having to use my right mouse button to *Remove and Sort* my using statements and am constantly forgetting.

Assuming that I’m not using Re-Sharper is there any way to extend the <kbd>Ctrl + K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl + D</kbd> keyboard shortcut to format my code and sort my using statements?

Would writing a macro to do both tasks and assigning it the same key combination the only way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the lack of response I can only assume that I'll need to create a macro and assign it the same keyboard shortcuts... oh well

```
Sub LazyFormatAndSortUsingMacro()
    DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.FormatDocument")
    DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.RemoveAndSort")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 7):

It's not extending the current key combo as such, but there's a Edit.RemoveAndSort command to which you can assign a key binding in Tools -> Options -> Keyboard.

[Here's](http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2008/01/29/VisualStudio2008ResolvingNamespacesRemovingUnusedUsingStatementsTip.aspx) a blog post detailing just that.

Comment: I know that it sounds petty but I really wanted something that would do both Edit.RemoveAndSort as well as Edit.FormatDocument